How to Configure a Windows User to Pass a Specific .NET Identity Check?
I'm working on a .NET application that uses WindowsIdentity and WindowsPrincipal to check user permissions based on their group membership. The method below evaluates whether the user is an administrator or belongs to a specific group based on their SID. I need to test a specific condition where a user is not actually an administrator but is recognized as one based on another claim.
Here's the method in question:
private const string LocalAdministratorsGroupSID = "S-1-5-32-544"; // well-known Administrators group SID

public static bool CheckIdentity(WindowsIdentity identity)
{
   var clientWindowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
   return clientWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ||
          clientWindowsPrincipal.Claims.Any(c => c.Value == LocalAdministratorsGroupSID);
}

Goal:
I aim to create a test user that:

Does not actually have administrator rights (IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) returns false).
Does have a claim with the SID of the Administrators group ("S-1-5-32-544"), making the second part of the condition (clientWindowsPrincipal.Claims.Any) return true.

Question:
How can I configure a user or manipulate the WindowsIdentity object in a test environment to achieve this? I'm exploring how to either simulate or manually inject such claims primarily for testing purposes. Any guidance on approaching this in a .NET context would be particularly helpful.

The question is unclear. If you want to create a test user, just create a test user in Windows's Local Users and Groups tool. By the time your method is called authentication has already completed. To check if a user belongs to a group you can use .IsInRole("ThatGroupName"). You don't have to know the SID. If you do know it, there's an .IsInRole(SecurityIdentifier) overload that accepts a group SID

I just want to create a scenario where the first part of the condition would evaluate as false and the second one as true. Is that even possible?

What do you mean? You can easily check whether someone is in one group or another. Even better, you can put Administrators in the LocalAppAdministrators group and only allow that group. In a desktop application you can prevent non-members from even starting the application.

Hypothetical scenario. I want to create a user that's not a member of WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator, yet has a claim to LocalAdministratorsGroupSID = "S-1-5-32-544". Question boils down it, aren't my two conditions redundant? I just want to check if user is local admin (or has equivalent rights).

Yes, they're redundant. They refer to the same group. The value of WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator is 544, if you use new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid,null); the SID is S-1-5-32-544

All values in WindowsBuiltInRole correspond to built-in security groups
